C# reading memory of other process on Linux
I'm trying to learn memory manipulation and pointers.
I want to read the memory of a process, let's say at address 0x1234ABCD
If I read it with GDB using p/x *(uint64_t*)0x1234ABCD I get the desired value (A pointer, in format of 0xABCDEFGH)
But if I try to read it in C# with the function I made (see the function below) then I get a useless byte read, which is not the expected output (GDB gives the correct output)
Instead I get a nonsense like 00909FC7817C0000
What could be the issue?
Code:
public static byte[] ReadMemory(int pid, long address, int length)
        {
            try
            {
                string memPath = $"/proc/{pid}/mem";
                Console.WriteLine($"Reading memory from: {memPath}");

                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(memPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
                    fs.Seek(address, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    int bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, length);

                    if (bytesRead != length)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Warning: Expected to read {length} bytes but read {bytesRead} bytes.");
                    }

                    return buffer;
                }
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: Unauthorized access. Try running as root or with appropriate permissions.");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error reading memory: " + ex.Message);
            }

            return null;
        }

And here is how do I call it: byte[] buffer = ReadMemory(pid, pointer, 8);

Related : https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6302
